# How to detect if string is a URI

Tags: javascript, html, regex, file, function

I use this function to detect whether a string is a URL:

```
function ValidUrl(str) {
    var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?' + // protocol
    '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|' + // domain name
    '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))' + // OR ip (v4) address
    '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*' + // port and path
    '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?' + // query string
    '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$', 'i'); // fragment locator
    if (!pattern.test(str)) {
        alert(str + " is not a valid URL.");
        return false;
    } else {
        alert(str + " is a valid URL.");
        return true;
    }
}
```

But, I need to see if the string is a URI, `file://`, `chrome-extension://` & `ftp://` included.

How would I go about doing this? Complete novice with RegExp...

Comment: You have picked a problem that's larger than novice-size in regex. :-) Also, consider that there are many URLs that are technically malformed but work in practice -- your users don't care about the technical aspect, they will just think that the URL works fine and your stupid program doesn't understand that.

Comment: This might help you [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first string in concatenation with this:

```
^((https?|file|ftp|chrome-extension):\/\/)?
```

Comment: Or use `^((https?|file|s?ftps?|chrome-extension):\/\/)?` to also include `ftps` and `sftp`

Comment: or use `^(([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z.+-]*):\/\/)?` to match URIs with any syntactically possible scheme